ASTRO framework POST METHOD is not working
i am using astro framework here is my code in src/components/test.astro
and form is displaying properly.
<form id="contact-form">
  <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" required />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- Optional: Message to display after submission -->
<div id="success-message" style="display: none;">Thank you for your submission!</div>

<script>
  // Wait until the DOM is fully loaded
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting the usual way and refreshing the page

      const formData = new FormData(form);
      const firstName = formData.get('first-name');

      // Prepare the data to send to the API
      const data = { firstName };

      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/test', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          document.getElementById('success-message').style.display = 'block';
          form.reset(); // Clear the form fields
        } else {
          alert('There was an issue submitting your form.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('Something went wrong!');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

and here is my test.ts code which is sitting in /api/test.ts
// src/pages/api/gravityform.ts
export async function POST({ request }: { request: Request }): Promise<Response> {
  try {
    const formData = new URLSearchParams(await request.text()); // Parse form data
    const firstName = formData.get('firstName'); // Extract first name from form data
    console.log('Received first name:', firstName);

    // Process the form data (e.g., store in a database)
    // For simplicity, we will just return the data received
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({
        message: `Form submitted successfully. First Name: ${firstName}`,
      }),
      { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing POST request:', error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error processing POST request', error: error.message }),
      { status: 500, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    );
  }
}

and when i trying to submit my form i am getting this error  on console

error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5682:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5663:27)
    at consumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5669:9)
    at _Request.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5609:18)
    at Module.POST (C:/xampp/htdocs/triptodurstatic/src/pages/api/test.ts:5:32)


and i am not usind vue/ react or client side rendering. in config i am using output mode as hybrid  and if use server mode its working fine. since this code is developed by someone else i am not allowed to change config to server

What is the path and filename of this file?

@Phil its src/pages/submit-form.astro . i tried with submit-form.js as well

Looks like your file path doesn't match the request you're using (where is the /api part). I'd try src/pages/api/submit-form.js. See also these docs... "Your routes will be rendered on demand by default in server mode. In hybrid mode, you must opt out of prerendering for each custom endpoint with export const prerender = false"

i am using hybrid mode. sorry i am very new in astro framework. what excalt i need to do

Your file is currently named src/pages/submit-form.astro. I think it should be src/pages/api/submit-form.js to match your request http://localhost:4321/api/submit-form

@Phil not working this way. getting server error now

And the error message is...?

What happened to your endpoint code? That still seems very relevant

Also, the filename for your (new) endpoint should be src/pages/api/test.js. Is that what it is?

@Phil i changed the file name to test.ts and its seems working but getting above error

"and here is my test.ts code which is sitting in /api/test.ts"... I think you forgot to include the code in your question

@Phil yes you are right. i added code and if i change config to server its working

@Phil it worked now , thanks for your help

btw. why do you even need client-side JavaScript? this is muuuch easier and less brittle: https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/build-forms/

@mb21 i need it look like ajax submit. i tried above and its refreshing the page which i dont want
